# Mostrar los productos cargados en un array en un sector especifico

Tags: javascript, css, html5, eventos

Tengo un array con productos, y cada producto se muestra en el HTML. Entonces, quiero, que cuando uno haga click en el botón "Agregar al carrito", los productos agregados se muestren en este cuadrado, donde uno pueda hacer scroll, sin que el cuadrado cambie de dimensiones. Adjunto imagen del cuadrado.
[image: Imagen del cuadrado]

Mi código de Javascript es:

```
class Producto {
    constructor(id, descripcion) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
}
let productos = [];
let carritos = [];

productos.push(new Producto("751100", "Manija"));
productos.push(new Producto("851100", "Manija"));
productos.push(new Producto("751200", "Manija"));
productos.push(new Producto("753100", "Manija"));

let section = document.querySelector('.tiendaOnline.row.separar.container-fluid');

for (const producto of productos) {
    let article = document.createElement("article");
    article.className = "col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 carta"
    article.innerHTML = `   <img src="../imagenes/ft-nosotros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Imagen de Producto">
                            <div>
                            
                            <h3 class="codigo">${producto.id}</h3>
                            <p class="descripcion">${producto.descripcion}</p>
                            <p>Precio</p>

                                <div>
                                    <div class="btnCompra">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
                            </svg>
                                    <a href="" id="${producto.id}">Agregar al Carrito</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="" id="detalles${producto.id}" class="btnDetalles">Ver detalles</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
    // Agregar a sección y no al documento
    section.appendChild(article);

    let articleProducto = document.getElementById(producto.id);
    articleProducto.onclick = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        carritos.push(event.target.id);
    }
    console.log(carritos);
}
```

Y mi HTML es:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42" fill="currentColor" id="svgCart" class="bi bi-cart svgCart"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
        </svg>
        <section id="carrito" class="noShow">
            
        </section>
```

Donde `id="carrito"` es donde se tendrán que mostrar los productos. Probé con overflow, pero no funcionó. No sé qué puede ser...

Muchas Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy sencillo con CSS, asigna una altura fija al contenedor y haz que aparezca una barra de desplazamiento cuando el contenido supere esa altura con la propiedad [overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y):

```css
#carrito {
    width: 300px;
    /* Asigna una altura fija, la que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades */
    height: 150px;
    /* Agregar barra de desplazamiento cuando sea necesario */
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<section id="carrito">
    <p>Producto 1</p>
    <p>Producto 2</p>
    <p>Producto 3</p>
    <p>Producto 4</p>
    <p>Producto 5</p>
    <p>Producto 6</p>
    <p>Producto 7</p>
</section>
```